# Javascript Objects - call() method

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have a doubt on below code**

```
function Product(name, price) {
  this.name = name;
  this.price = price;
}

function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';
}

var x = new Food('cheese', 5);
console.log(x.name);
console.log(x.price);
console.log(x.category);
// expected output: "cheese"
```

I was practicing JS Objects in MDN, in the inheritance topic I was reading about `call()`method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call , the doubt is in the Food function we are not passing category argument, how it still works in console?

After seeing this code I tried with an example, but ended-up with error

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 It's also not at all clear what you're asking. You don't have to pass a category to `Food` because it has it hardcoded. The code in your picture doesn't work because you're trying to use an undeclared variable.

Comment: Okay, Thanks bro, sure I'll post the it wanted to be

Answer (score 1):

> the doubt is in the Food function we are not passing category argument,
>   how it still works in console?

because `category` is initialized with `food` inside the `Food` constructor function

```
function Food(name, price) {
  Product.call(this, name, price);
  this.category = 'food';            <------ category initialized
}
```

Comment: Now it's well clear, and it worked on my console. Being hard-coded property it is not required to pass them as args. Thank you bro once again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have parameters on function p. Add what you placed inside the function. P(name, place)
Ps: pertaining to the error.